# JavaCC for .NET?

Tags: .net, parser-generator, javacc

I've been spending some time doing JavaCC parser generation for assignments at University and was wondering if there is a similar simple parser generator framework for .NET available?

I know there is ANTLR, but I found it a bit too big for my taste and really started to like the simplicity that JavaCC brings..

greetings Daniel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio SDK ships with MPPG and MPLEX which are based on Gardens Point GPPG and GPLEX.

Found for 2008 in:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 SDK\VisualStudioIntegration\Tools\Bin
```

An example language support for Visual Studio can be found in:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 SDK\VisualStudioIntegration\Samples\IDE\CSharp\Example.ManagedMyC
```

Comment: You could also try Microsoft Oslo SDK which ships with a very simple parsers generator.